# Overflowed (i.e. querystring) RouteData back out of the controller into the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Anyone understand why the following doesn't work?

What I want to do is copy current route data plus whatever I add via an anonymous object into new routedata when forming new links on the view.

For example if I have the parameter "page" as a non route path (i.e. so it overflows the route path and its injected into the method parameter if a querystring is present) e.g.

```
public ActionResult ChangePage(int? page)  { }
```

and I want the View to know the updated page when building links using helpers. I thought the best way to do this is with the following:

```
public ActionResult ChangePage(int? page)
{
     if(page.HasValue)
        RouteData.Values.Add("Page", page);
      ViewData.Model = GetData(page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1);
}
```

Then in the view markup I can render my next, preview, sort, showmore (any links relevant) with this overload:

```
 public static class Helpers
{
    public static string ActionLinkFromRouteData(this HtmlHelper helper,  string linkText, string actionName, object values)
    {
        RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

        foreach(var routeValue in helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values)
        {
            if(routeValue.Key != "controller" && routeValue.Key != "action")
            {
                routeValueDictionary[routeValue.Key] = routeValue;
            }
        }

        foreach(var prop in GetProperties(values))
        {
            routeValueDictionary[prop.Name] = prop.Value;
        }

        return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, routeValueDictionary;

    }

   private static IEnumerable<PropertyValue> GetProperties(object o)
   {
    if (o != null) {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(o);
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props) {
            object val = prop.GetValue(o);
            if (val != null) {
                yield return new PropertyValue { Name = prop.Name, Value = val };
            }
        }
    }
   }

    private sealed class PropertyValue 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have posted the code only to illustrate the point. This doesn't work and doesn't feel right... Pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the page info into ViewData?

`PagedResultsInfo` (or something) sounds like a class you could write too... we do.